# BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER AND CHANGED FIELDS new and old

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER AND CHANGED FIELDS new and old

If a record is updated I have a triger that manipulates some of the columns in the data
One field is "QTY" which can change or not change when other columns/fields are changed
which cause the trigger to be executed

If QTY is changed I want to execute the logic, if it does not change I want no action to
be taken and the value of "QTY" to remain unchanged.

It seems that if QTY is not changed that "OLD.QTY" and "NEW.QTY" have different values

What condition can I use to see if "QTY" has changed

If the "QTY" does not change will the value of NEW.QTY = "null" consistasntly

Comment: "What condition can I use to see if "QTY" has changed" not completly clear what you mean without seeing the trigger code SQL.. I think a CASE END statement is the best suited.. `CASE WHEN OLD.QTY <> NEW.QTY THEN ... ELSE ... END`

Answer (score 0):

When the column `c1` is unchanged, a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger will have `OLD.c1` and `NEW.c1` set to the same value, because that was the value both before and after the update.

The expression `(OLD.c1 <=> NEW.c1)` evaluates as `TRUE` when the column value is unchanged, else `FALSE`.

The expression `(NOT (OLD.c1 <=> NEW.c1))` evaluates as `TRUE` if the column value is changed, else `FALSE`.

Don't use `=` or `!=` or `<>` for comparisons in update triggers, unless you *fully* understand the implications of [3VL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), because these are not null-safe operators.

Comment: On the new.qty I was performing calculations assuming the new.qty was the same as old.qty since there was no new entry for qty.

Comment: I then was getting garbage results for the new.qty, I then tested the new.qty = null and if it was I set the new.qty=old.qty and this seemed to fix the problem

Comment: @PeteWattersChatsworth note that there is no possible value `x` where the expression `x = null` will **ever** evaluate to true, including when `x` is also `null`.  Nothing is equal to `null`, since `null` is not a value -- it's a condition, indicating the absence of any value.

Comment: How can you check for null

Comment: There is an `IS NULL` operator... `IF foo IS NULL THEN ...`